# My batch file is not running with post-build event

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I can't tell if my batch file is running during the post-build event process.I'm trying to sign a .dll file for certification and i'm using a batch file to run after a build.

I am using the call `"$(ProjectDir)Test_Sign_dll_C#2.bat"`
The C# project compiles but after I check if the dll is signed I find that there is no digital signature.

I have this listed in the Post-build event:

```
call "$(ProjectDir)Test_Sign_dll_C#2.bat"
```

I am using the signtool.exe like this:

```
signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f MpCertTest.pfx /p for C:\Users\"Target location"
```

Project builds with no errors, after I check the dll in the bin\debug folder it is not signed with digital Certificate.If I run the .bat file manually it will sign the dll.

Comment: Look at the output window, where console output from build events appears. A few `echo`s commands may help diagnose if the bat file indeed ran.

Comment: this is what i'm getting. 'signtool.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.

Comment: @MarioPerez - Try putting the full path to signtool.exe in you .bat file. I'm not 100% sure why it would work manually but give you that error in the post-build event though.

Comment: Took your advice and seems like it worked.                                                            I used @ECHO OFF
cd C:\Users\mperez\Desktop\Make a Cert and Sign
signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f MpCertTest.pfx /p test123 C:\Users\"target dll location"
PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I used the following commands in the post-build event section in VS 15:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Users\mperez\Desktop\Make a Cert and Sign
signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f MpCertTest.pfx /p test123 C:\Users\"Target Location for .dll
PAUSE
```